# The (?) French cuisine

Tags: definite-articles, abstract-nouns

Phrases like "French cuisine", "Italian cuisine", "Russian cuisine" seem to be used both with and without definite article. Is there any rule to this? I looked at a few hundred results of Google book search and I could not find any pattern.

The definite article seems to be used in a non-negligible minority of cases.

There is one case when the article seems to be required, namely when there is an additional qualifier of some kind (when talking about some specific instance, so to speak, of e.g. French cuisine). Here are a couple of examples:

- Maybe it was the high level of the French cuisine she served in her restaurant once a month.
- The ambiance there was regal, the French cuisine imperial.

But there are many examples without any qualifiers:

- THE most glorious dishes of the French cuisine have been created for chicken.
- A visit to France can be your introduction to the imagination, spirit and tradition of the French cuisine.
- We sampled various restaurants and enjoyed the French cuisine.

All examples are from Google book search.

Comment: I could say ***the*** *French cuisine **of that restaurant** is great*, but I don't see how that's any different than the way we use the definite article in general. What is leading you to think that *cuisine*, in particular, is treated differently? Can you provide an example of some unusual use of paring *the* with *cuisine*? Otherwise, you're just asking how the definite article is used.

Comment: @JasonBassford yes, this is one case when the article would be required, but I see it being used a lot for the cuisine in general. I will provide a couple of examples (from google book search), give me a few minutes.

Comment: Also keep this in mind: (1) *Water is wet.* (2) ***The*** *water is wet.* Both of those things are fine. The first is talking about water in general, while the second is talking about a specific body of water. (And the second wouldn't be used without a previously established context.)

Comment: Of the examples “without qualifiers,” the first two strike me as errors. Not everything in Google books is standard written English.

Comment: What happened to German cuisine? British?

Comment: None of the added examples in the question necessarily demonstrate anything different that the regular rules of the use of the definite article and any noun. It's also likely that in several of the cases (in particular the first two under "without any qualifiers"), prior reference to a specific cuisine was already made. You cannot just look at some of these sentences in isolation to the rest of the text that came before. Or, as another comment suggested, they could just be errors.

Comment: @Xanne these countries don't have "cuisine", they have food! jk